# If Line Matches Anything After String, Then Do Command

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, awk, grep

I'm fairly good with grep, cut, sed, etc. However, I'm having a tough time extracting this data from a file. It looks like this:

```
--timestamp--  data://example1// -----| This could be anything or nothing
--timestamp--  data://example2// -----|     This could be something
--timestamp--  data://example3// -----| 
--timestamp--  data://example4// -----|      This could something else
--timestamp--  data://example5// -----| This could be another something
--timestamp--  data://example6// -----| 
--timestamp--  data://example7// -----|       This could something else
```

I would like to return all lines that have anything after the string `-----|` so the output would be:

```
example1
example2
example4
example5
example7
```

I know that I need to use an IF statement based on a `grep '-----|.*$'` match. It would be if there is any characters after the string, then output the line. Then, I could pipe to an awk command that would extract between the delimiters `//` before and after example. I'm just really stuck on how to structure the if statement.

Any help with this IF statement would be very appreciated.

Comment: No need for an `if`, a grep (or two) would suffice.

Comment: "all lines that have anything after", did you mean "all lines that have nothing after"?

Comment: Sorry, just updated the question. I definitely want anything after.

Comment: Instead of adding comments that say "this could be anything or something", create sample input/output that doesn't contain any text your real files don't contain and that SHOWS sample input rather than trying to describe it. You absolutely do NOT need an IF statement after grep - the entire solution will be one concise awk script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk to do this using `//` as field separator and print the 2nd field:

```
awk -F'//' '/-{5}\|[ \t]*[^ \t]/{print $2}' file

example1
example2
example4
example5
example7
```

Regex: `/-{5}\|[ \t]*[^ \t]/` searches for five dashed followed by a literal pipe followed by 0 or more whitespace and then a non-whitespace character.

You can also use POSIX class `[[:blank:]]` to match a space or tab:

```
awk -F'//' '/-{5}\|[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]/{print $2}' file
```

Comment: Hey Anubhava, the second POSIX class is looking good. Just testing it out a little more.

Comment: `[[:blank:]]*` can just be `.*`.

Comment: Yes it can be but performance wise `[[:blank:]]*` will be better without any backtracking.

Comment: Why? I'd have thought checking for a specific subset of characters would be slower than just any character but I'd expect it to be an insignificant difference anyway. idk what backtracking has to do with it.

Comment: For smaller dataset difference is really insignificant. But in general `DOT` matches any character and regex engine needs to stop matching `.*` after regex engine sees what is after `.*`. On the other hand `[[:blank:]]` will match just space or tab so regex engine doesn't need to check for what is next.

Comment: Butwith `[[:blank:]]` the regexp engine has to check "is this a blank" for each character whereas for `.` it doesn't. idk, maybe you're right, just not obvious to me that `[[:blank:]]*` would be faster than `.*` even given your point about checking what's next. Personally I'd favor brevity over performance in this case anyway though.

Comment: No worthwhile regex implementation will do anything resembling "backtracking" due to a `.*` pattern. That might be what the Perl internals will do.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a single `grep`:

```
grep -oP '[^/]*(?=// -----\| .+$)' input.txt

example1
example2
example4
example5
example7
```

The idea is to match starting from the text between the `/` all the way to end of the line. I use the `-o` flag which returns only the matched portion of each line. This works nicely in conjunction with the lookahead (i.e. the `(?=...)` part) which matches the pattern inside it but does not include the matched text in the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'/' '!/\|$/{print $3}' file
example1
example2
example4
example5
example7
```

Make the condition `/\|[[:blank:]]*$/` if you want to treat blanks after the `|` as if they didn't exist.

Note that this approach will fail given a line like:

```
--timestamp--  data://example1// -----| "anything" includes |
```

If that can happen then include it in your example. You could change the condition to match `-----|` by that also qualifies as "anything":

```
--timestamp--  data://example1// -----| "anything" includes -----|
```

and so could still cause failures. Just be accurate and truly representative with your sample input/output and include the worst-case scenarios not just the sunny day cases.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Sorry I couldn't provide more detail. The answer I chose does take care of the issue for me. I appreciate the help though. Much kudos.

Comment: Sure but there's other possible cases it won't take care of depending on what "anything" really means and there may be a much simpler solution, also depending on what "anything" really means.

Answer (score 0):

In your example data there are spaces after the | (or maybe just an artifact of copying).  If those aren't really there, just change the pattern to match from `/\| .+$/` to `/\|.+$/` - delete the space.

This matches all lines where there is nothing after the '| ' combo:

```
$ awk -F/ '!/\| .+$/ {print $3}' < t
example3
example6
```

This matches all lines where there is something after the '| ' combo:

```
$awk -F/ '/\| .+$/ {print $3}' < t
example1
example2
example4
example5
example7
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another `awk`

```
$ awk -F'-----\\|' '$2~/[^ ]+$/{n=split($1,a,"//"); print a[n-1]}' file

example1
example2
example4
example5
example7
```

this handles extra delimiter case.